# How do a site detect if there is VLC/FFMPEG live streaming?

Tags: php, stream, live

User(s) decide to start a stream toward my site, VLC and FFMPEG is able to do that. But how could a site detect that he is getting stream(s)?
Because I want it to then display on a page "`current live videos`". And what kind of streams should I need to use? HTTP? RTSP? UPD?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of media server for that, like Wowza, Red5 or Adobe Flash Media Server. The protocol depends on your media server choice.

To display that information you need to program the server to communicate with the site somehow. For Wowza probably the easiest is if it writes the available streams to a database. For Adobe FMS it's probably the best to use a gateway to do that via AMF. You need either Zend_AMF, or AMFPHP for the gateway code, if you use PHP for that.

Comment: hmm, looks good. If I just make a socket connection for receiving that? Sadly if I set up a simple "server" to a port, it wont accept any datas